# Merging arrays in a multidimensional array with a common value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I have the following multidimensional array below. I'm trying to check for arrays that has the same `StartingDateTime` . If they do, I want to merge them into one array but I only want to retain the values of `TWHour`, `TEHour` and have them renamed to `TWHour1`, `TEHour1`. After that I want to unset the other arrays with the same `StartingDateTime`.

Important Note: The number of arrays that can have the same `StartingDateTime` can be more than 2. So if there are more than 2, the renaming of `TWHour` & `TEHour` should be continuous. E.g if there are 3 arrays that were combined, it there would be `TWHour1`, `TWHour2`, `TWHour3`, and so on.

I currently have this code. It can merge the arrays and rename them to 1. It also deletes the array with the same `StartingDateTime`. However, the code have certain problems. Firstly, it gives me an undefined concept error because of the first if statement. Second, its limited to one merge, if there are more then it won't merge the rest. Lastly, when I unset, the number it skips the array no. it deleted. At the result you can see that `$items[3]` is missing. Normally, using unset will just replace the missing array.

Any help will be very appreciated.

```
$checker = 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {

    // if they have the same StartingDateTime
    if ($items[$i]['StartingDateTime'] == $items[$checker]['StartingDateTime']) {

        // Transfer the values from the identified duplicate 
        // Have it renamed to TWHourx where x is the number of duplicates
        $items[$i]["TWHour1"] = $items[$checker]['TWHour'];
        $items[$i]["TEHour1"] = $items[$checker]['TEHour'];
        // After moving the values to the $i array
        // Delete the duplicated arrays  
        unset($items[$checker]);

        // 2nd Layer of filter, more filters will probably have similar codes    
        $checker2 = $checker + 1;
        if ($items[$i]['StartingDateTime'] == $items[$checker2]['StartingDateTime']) {
            $items[$i]["TWHour2"] = $items[$checker2]['TWHour'];
            $items[$i]["TEHour2"] = $items[$checker2]['TEHour'];
        }

        unset($items[$checker2]);
        $items = array_values($items);
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }

    // Count($items) changes once it unsets an array
    // new count to get the new count value of $items array
    $newcount = count($items);
    if ($checker < $newcount) {
        $checker++;
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }

}
```

> Extract of filtered $items array

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 30 in line 116

[25] => Array
    (
        [StartingDateTime] => 2016-06-26
        [TWHour] => 00:00:00
        [TEHour] => 01:00:00
        [NoOfHoursWorked] => 10
        [NoOfHoursRest] => 14
        [Comments] => want
        [NoOfHoursRestAny24HR] => 14
        [NoOfHoursRestAny7Day] => 98
        [TWHour1] => 04:00:00
        [TEHour1] => 05:00:00
        [TWHour2] => 12:00:00
        [TEHour2] => 16:00:00
    )
```

> $items Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [StartingDateTime] => 2016-06-26
            [TWHour] => 19:30:00
            [TEHour] => 23:30:00
            [NoOfHoursWorked] => 10
            [NoOfHoursRest] => 14
            [Comments] => any time
            [NoOfHoursRestAny24HR] => 14
            [NoOfHoursRestAny7Day] => 98
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [StartingDateTime] => 2016-06-27
            [TWHour] => 13:30:00
            [TEHour] => 23:30:00
            [NoOfHoursWorked] => 10
            [NoOfHoursRest] => 14
            [Comments] => I 
            [NoOfHoursRestAny24HR] => 14
            [NoOfHoursRestAny7Day] => 98
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [StartingDateTime] => 2016-06-28
            [TWHour] => 03:00:00
            [TEHour] => 05:00:00
            [NoOfHoursWorked] => 10
            [NoOfHoursRest] => 14
            [Comments] => want
            [NoOfHoursRestAny24HR] => 14
            [NoOfHoursRestAny7Day] => 98
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [StartingDateTime] => 2016-06-28
            [TWHour] => 13:30:00
            [TEHour] => 23:30:00
            [NoOfHoursWorked] => 10
            [NoOfHoursRest] => 14
            [Comments] => want
            [NoOfHoursRestAny24HR] => 14
            [NoOfHoursRestAny7Day] => 98
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [StartingDateTime] => 2016-06-29
            [TWHour] => 13:30:00
            [TEHour] => 23:30:00
            [NoOfHoursWorked] => 10
            [NoOfHoursRest] => 14
            [Comments] => to rest
            [NoOfHoursRestAny24HR] => 14
            [NoOfHoursRestAny7Day] => 98
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [StartingDateTime] => 2016-06-30
            [TWHour] => 12:30:00
            [TEHour] => 23:30:00
            [NoOfHoursWorked] => 10
            [NoOfHoursRest] => 14
            [Comments] => hehe
            [NoOfHoursRestAny24HR] => 14
            [NoOfHoursRestAny7Day] => 98
        )

)
```

> Expected Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [StartingDateTime] => 2016-06-26
            [TWHour] => 19:30:00
            [TEHour] => 23:30:00
            [NoOfHoursWorked] => 10
            [NoOfHoursRest] => 14
            [Comments] => any time
            [NoOfHoursRestAny24HR] => 14
            [NoOfHoursRestAny7Day] => 98
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [StartingDateTime] => 2016-06-27
            [TWHour] => 13:30:00
            [TEHour] => 23:30:00
            [NoOfHoursWorked] => 10
            [NoOfHoursRest] => 14
            [Comments] => I 
            [NoOfHoursRestAny24HR] => 14
            [NoOfHoursRestAny7Day] => 98
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [StartingDateTime] => 2016-06-28
            [TWHour] => 03:00:00
            [TEHour] => 05:00:00
            [NoOfHoursWorked] => 10
            [NoOfHoursRest] => 14
            [Comments] => want
            [NoOfHoursRestAny24HR] => 14
            [NoOfHoursRestAny7Day] => 98
            [TWHour1] => 13:30:00
            [TEHour1] => 23:30:00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [StartingDateTime] => 2016-06-29
            [TWHour] => 13:30:00
            [TEHour] => 23:30:00
            [NoOfHoursWorked] => 10
            [NoOfHoursRest] => 14
            [Comments] => to rest
            [NoOfHoursRestAny24HR] => 14
            [NoOfHoursRestAny7Day] => 98
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [StartingDateTime] => 2016-06-30
            [TWHour] => 12:30:00
            [TEHour] => 23:30:00
            [NoOfHoursWorked] => 10
            [NoOfHoursRest] => 14
            [Comments] => hehe
            [NoOfHoursRestAny24HR] => 14
            [NoOfHoursRestAny7Day] => 98
        )

)
```

EDIT: Updated my code. It merges butwhen I try to add in another layer of filter for more arrays with the same StartingDateTime. I keep getting an undefined offset error again.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use **array_values** that will reset your index of array. use after filter

```
$items = array_values($items);
```

Updated Code :- $item that will be your duplicated array and $finalArr will be final result array

```
$finalArr = array();
foreach($items as $key=>$val){
    $k = searchForId($val['StartingDateTime'],$finalArr);
    if($k != 'blank'){
        $finalArr[$key]['TWHour1'] = $val['TWHour'];
        $finalArr[$key]['TEHour1'] = $val['TEHour'];
    } else {
        $finalArr[] = $val; 
    }
}

public function  searchForId($strDateTime,$array) {

    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if(array_key_exists('StartingDateTime', $val)){
            if ($val['StartingDateTime'] == $strDateTime) {
               return $key;
            }
        }
    }
    return 'blank';
}
```

Comment: I'm speechless.. It actually worked. Thank you very much sir, your answer really helped me a lot. I truly appreciate it, it solved most of the problems. Do you have any ideas on how can I merge more arrays if there are more arrays that have a common StartingDateTime?

Comment: Use these one $array = array_unique (array_merge ($array1, $array2));

Comment: I'm not really sure how to implement that because I only want to retain the value of TWHour and TEHour and have them renamed to TWHour1 and TEHour1. I tried to implement it but it gave me parameter and argument errors.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I only had the chance now to try the code. I'm getting an undefined index: StartingDateTime. This line, if ($val['StartingDateTime'] == $strDateTime)

Comment: It works but it only extracts the hours and doesn't merge to the array with same StartingDateTime. Additionally, it doesn't rename the TEHour and TWHour to TWHour1, TEHour1, TWHour2, TEHour2,  when there are multiple arrays that has the same StartingDateTime

Comment: I updated my code. Since the previous code for the first filtering is already working. I tried adding another layer of filter but experienced another undefined offset.